# Check if values are equal in Python IF statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 values , one of them is coming from a file and one of them is coming from database. Both values are numeric . My code is Python, 2.7 version.

If I do use below code , it is working like charm

```
if int(val1) == int(val2) :
  print "what ever action it will do"
```

My question is if there is a different way to make that check? Is this an acceptable way to do that or not?

Comment: It is completely acceptable.

Comment: Its a pretty good way for doing it, basic one. Just check if this suits for your problem, if it works its ok.

Comment: If you're wanting to check their numeric equality then you got it right there!

Comment: Only purpose is to check if they are equal numbers or not. Nothing else

Comment: If you are going to use them as ints, then I would say convert them as they come out of file/db

Answer (score 3):

if your database (or file reading module) gives you ints, you can omit one of the int-conversions, but otherwise it's fine. 
You usually would skip the blank in front of the `:`.

If there is any possibility that one of your values might not be convertable to an int (e.g. any other string), you should use a try-except-block to handle that error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an acceptable way to do that or not?

It depend from previous code. On first glance it work.

> is if there is a different way to make that check?

You can check it trick way:

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: val1 = "12.50"; val2 = 12.5
In [3]: (float(val1) == float(val2) and sys.stdout.write("what ever action it will do"))
what ever action it will do
```

Comment: Linuxoid will write it that way. Works but not very Pythonic

Comment: One should be careful when jesting around noobs. They may take you seriously

Comment: @volcano I have warned about it in answer. Furthemore it more Lisp-style then Linux-style.

Answer (score 0):

I both are numeric, then type casting is not required. You can use like the below code:

```
 if(val1==val2):
   print "what ever action it will do"
```

Comment: ok what if this files are coming from db from varchar(x) defined cell.  yes they are numeric but how python will react ? will it count values as string or integer ?